# Free geocoding services that allow fast geocoding of 300,000 addresses

Tags: geocoding

I have got a database with 300.000 addresses, zipcodes and addresses. Now the next step is to convert all those addresses to LAT LONG since that is what I now need.

I have looked at google maps api but it only offers 2500 queryies a day, which would mean 150 days aprox. to convert all those addresses. Is there another possibility that is FREE that could help me fix my problem?

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also try for MapQuest or Cloud Made. I have created a small utility while working on the same, I find it good for comparison. The utility is hosted at the below url:

http://ankit-zalani.appspot.com/GeoCode/index.jsp

Answer (score 0):

[Yahoo's geocoding API](http://developer.yahoo.com/geo/placefinder/) allows 50,000 requests per day.

Microsoft offers geocoding via [Bing Maps Services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff701702.aspx) but I couldn't see what the limits are.  You probably need to create an account to find out.

Answer (score 0):

I once had a similar problem and I can tell you, an exact approach depends on specifics of your data. For example, I've seen couple of services allowing you to geocode US zipcodes with really high limits of requests/day.

In my case the data was addresses from a country in Europe, so I was left with open APIs of major companies like Microsoft, Google or Yahoo.

Unfortunately after reading their limits of requests/day and terms of use, I realized it would take too long to geocode all of the addresses. I then found Open Street Maps. You can download the data (which is freely available) for whatever geographical region you need, parse it (it's in XML), load it into a database (free PostgreSQL in my case) and write your own geocoder.

Sure, it won't find all addresses, but you can save the problematic ones and geocode them using an API from Google for example. In my case, it was just a small fraction of all the data I was starting with, so it was worth it.

Also check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8782165/1820695) to a similar question, which mentions a Microsoft API (that I am not familiar with), which supposedly has high limits on the input data.