# What's the easiest way to do a one-time mass geocode? (580,000 addresses)

Tags: geocoding

I am working on a civics related project and I need to be able to display all the properties in the City of Philadelphia on a map, so I'll need to get the latitude & longitude for all 580,000 properties. (Only once)

Most APIs like Google/Yahoo have limits of 5,000 per day, and even BatchGeo has a similar limit.

Is there a way I can do a one-time geocoding of all these addresses?

Answer (score 2):

You can find a list of free and paid geocoding services at [USC](https://webgis.usc.edu/Services/Geocode/About/GeocoderList.aspx) site.

Also check [Microsoft's Geocode Dataflow API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff701733.aspx), it allows up to 200,000 entries / 300 Mb and takes up to 14 days.

Another possibility to combine several services at once: use 4 services that allow 5,000 entries a day and you'll finish your task in a month.

Comment: Thanks! What about geocoding with ArcGIS or something? Someone mentioned that to me in passing, that it'd be unlimited.

Comment: It looks like you can use ArcGIS Geocoding Task Service only if you have ArcGIS installed. Anyway it permits to process only up to 1,000 entries per year: http://www.esri.com/software/arcgis/arcgisonline/world-geocoding.html

Answer (score 2):

You can use Map Quest of Cloud Made.
I have created a small utility to help compare these API's.
The utility is hosted at below url:

http://ankit-zalani.appspot.com/GeoCode/index.jsp

Comment: Doesn't work anymore. All 3 providers (Google, Mapquest and Cloud Made) return Javascript errors in teh console in the browser.

Comment: Will fix and let you know, thanks for letting me know.

Answer (score 1):

Tobias, I work for an address verification (and recently, geocoding) company called SmartyStreets.

Many services have usage restrictions based on volume and license agreements which prevent users from storing the results of geocoding queries. There are some vendors, however, which don't have limits or restrictions like that.

I would recommend something like [LiveAddress](http://www.smartystreets.com/products) which will not only geocode the addresses but also perform CASS-Certified verification to make sure your addresses are correct before giving you potentially faulty coordinates. You can run 580,000 or even millions at a time in a few minutes, and we allow you to store your results.

Hope this helps. If you have any more questions about addresses, I'll personally assist.

Comment: While this looks like a great service, it should be noted that it's $1k per month for unlimited lookups, as of my posting date

Comment: Yes, that's true; there was no mention of budget in the question so I figured it was irrelevant for the answer. However, the service is totally free for non-profits and startups.

Answer (score 0):

This thread is pretty old by now, but there have been some developments in recent years making bulk geocoding very cheap. My favorite option is to just obtain a geocoding server on AWS ( google: geocoding on aws), many options there, some free some with low hourly rates (total cost depends on the server you choose, of course.)